# About collision between an electron and photon

Tags: photons, electrons, conservation-laws, collision, inertial-frames

Can the collision between an electron and photon be inelastic? How about the energy loss in the collision as binding energy and photon bond with the electron due to high-energy collisions?

Comment: *How about the energy loss in the collision as binding energy* - What binding energy are you talking about?

Comment: I think it is $W_0$ as in the photoelectric effect $$ \frac{1}{2} m_e v^2 = W_0 + h f$$

Answer (score 2):

electrons and photons can indeed scatter off one another inelastically. this is called compton scattering. when it is the photon that gives some energy to the electron, it is called the compton effect. when it is the electron that gives up some energy to the photon, it is called the inverse compton effect.

Answer (score 1):

When electrons and photons collide, there is indeed inelastic collision.  As niels had mentioned about Compton scattering, I will elaborate more.  During Compton scattering, the photon loses energy, part of which is transferred to the electron.   However, Compton scattering is a mid-energy phenomena of light-matter interaction.  If you are looking for high-energy interactions, you need to read up on pair production, where a photon splits into a positron and electron due to high energies.